# How to set org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.SmartTransformerFactoryImpl as transformer in JBoss AS 7.0.2 Managed server

Tags: xslt, jboss7.x, transformer-model

I'm having a problem setting the *org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.SmartTransformerFactoryImpl* as the *javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory* when using the JBoss AS 7.0.2 in domain mode. If I put the following property in standalone.xml, everything works, but if I add the same in a server in host.xml (or in domain.xml) the server won't start.

```
<property name="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory" value="org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.SmartTransformerFactoryImpl"/>
```

I have in my deployment the xalan lib, but I even tried to put it as a global module. Nothing worked. I noticed the following error in console:

```
[Server:server-one] Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.SmartTransformerFactoryImpl not found
[Server:server-one]     at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:108)
[Server:server-one]     at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.<clinit>(__TransformerFactory.java:66)
[Server:server-one]     at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.initAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:82)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:88)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:75)
[Server:server-one]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:75)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:257)
```

If I simply remove the property the server works fine.

What else can I do??

I'm using the JBoss AS 7.0.2 Final.

[Link for the same question in JBoss community](https://community.jboss.org/message/732756)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that xalan is placed somewhere inside JBoss and it is not loaded yet on early startup phase.

Possible solutions:

- postpone system property assignment
- explicitly place xalan on jvm classpath so it can be loaded on early startup

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependency into MANIFEST file.

For instance JAR module that uses SmartTransformerFactoryImpl class should have the following line in MANIFEST file:

```
Dependencies: org.apache.xalan
```

If you are using maven you can configure it to add this line while packaging by adding the following configuration to maven JAR plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Dependencies>org.apache.xalan</Dependencies>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem during the migration of a webapp to Debian Jessie with apache2 and tomcat7, from an old (Lenny) Debian version.
I found the beginning of the solution thanks to [Direct Web Remoting: TransformerFactoryConfigurationError](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr2/other/fixes.html).

I solved it completely by moving xalan.jar **together with** xsltc.jar to CATALINA_HOME/lib which in my configuration is /usr/share/tomcat7/lib.
xalan.jar "alone" is not enough; it has to be "synchronized" with xsltc.jar, since in xalan.jar \org\apache\xalan\xsltc is empty, while xsltc.jar has \org\apache\xalan\xsltc\trax and there you have TransformerFactoryImpl class.
I suffered for a while with that issue so I hope sharing my experience might be helpful for someone.